# Extract Frequencies with magnitute values

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency

I have this matlab function which takes a .wav file and plots its FFT.

```
function [ output_args ] = plotFFT( file_name )

[file,Fs] = wavread(file_name);
L = length(file);

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
Y = fft(file,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

bar(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)))
```

From here, what do I do to detect peaks in the graph? I just need a list of frequencies of peaks with their magnitude values. I could just put a threshold, but it's not the best way, since high frequency harmonics have the magnitude similar to the low frequency noise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) and does it work for you?

Comment: @Schorsch I looked it up and it seems that this is what I need, thanks! Just need to tune it up a bit.